# how to display multiline content of textarea as it is

Tags: javascript

When the form is valid and I click <kbd>Save</kbd>, content of the `<textarea>` is saving with no issue, but when I click <kbd>Save</kbd> and it is invalid, it still renders but multiple lines from `<textarea>` are displaying on a single line with `\r\n` in between.

```
<td col span="3">
    <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="90" rows="10" tabindex="0"> 
       ${task.getData()?html}
    </textarea>
</td>
```

With the following in the `<textarea>`

```
test
test
      test
                test
```

I tried with

```
var val = elem('body').value;
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML=val;
```

it removes the `\r\n` but is rendered on a single line

I want text to be rendered as it is after validation.
Could you please help me out?

Comment: What is your server side language?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `"` to close your _rows_ attribute.

Comment: Sorry!! it's my mistake...actually rows="10" while pasting the code here, formatting is misplaced, server side language is java

Answer (score 0):

Change `rows` value, it's `1` in your code

```
<textarea name="body" id="body" cols="90" rows="3" tabindex="0">Hello</textarea>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkJZd/2/) and this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkJZd/1/) is using your code.

Comment: The second demo still contains the word _Hello_, it's just not on the top line so to see it you have to press the down arrow.

Comment: @PaulS., yes, exactly this is the `OP` has and I just gave him the example using his code in the second example.

Comment: I think the OP actually has new lines being converted to the string `"\\r\\n"` server side somewhere

Comment: Sorry!! it's my mistake...actually rows="10"

Comment: while pasting the code here, formatting is misplaced, but still getting the issue with \r\n and text rendered in single line

Answer (score 0):

I tried with following code and it is called after validation and it worked for me.

elem('body').value = elem('body').value.replace("\n\r","\n");

Comment: Initially I tried with same code, but i called it before validation..and hence it was not worked.